# What is `nvme0n1p2` in `lsblk` command output?

Tags: partition, disk, lsblk

In my Ubuntu 23.04 system, running `lsblk` gives the following output:

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
loop0         7:0    0     4K  1 loop /snap/bare/5
loop1         7:1    0  55.6M  1 loop /snap/core18/2745
loop2         7:2    0    73M  1 loop /snap/core22/607
loop3         7:3    0    73M  1 loop /snap/core22/617
loop4         7:4    0 460.6M  1 loop /snap/gnome-42-2204/102
loop5         7:5    0 460.6M  1 loop /snap/gnome-42-2204/87
loop6         7:6    0  91.7M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
loop7         7:7    0  12.3M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/959
loop8         7:8    0  53.2M  1 loop /snap/snapd/18933
loop9         7:9    0   452K  1 loop /snap/snapd-desktop-integration/83
sda           8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1        8:1    0    16M  0 part 
└─sda2        8:2    0 931.5G  0 part 
sr0          11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
nvme0n1     259:0    0 476.9G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0    16M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0   100M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0 276.2G  0 part 
└─nvme0n1p4 259:4    0 155.5G  0 part /
```

I was wondering what is the general "convention" of these names. Like what does `n1` and `p2` mean in `nvme0n1p2`? Also I was wondering, are `loop` mount points actually the ones we mount manually? Like mounting disk images?

Comment: The loops shown are all your snap applications. Your nvme0n1 is the drive and pY is the partition. The nX is a namespace often just 1.

Answer (score 1):

The `nX` refers to the namespace the drive/partition is in, whereas the `pX` refers to the partitions on the drive. For example, an NVME drive labeled `nvme0n1p3` would belong to namespace 1 and would be the 3rd partition.

In your case, the loops you have mounted are just snap applications. Snap packages create these 'virtual file systems' in order to better containerize and manage software.

`srX` refers to a device on a scsi controller, and `sdX` refers to a generic block device, usually an SSD HDD or USB.

Comment: I guess someone who asks such a question probably does not know what an NVMe namespace is. So one or two sentences about that would be helpful.